# ibanez edge III tremolo intonation out of adjustment

Tags: electric-guitar, intonation

i have an ibanez edge III trem and all my strings are 3 cents sharp for intonation. the adjusters are as far as they can go toward the neck..

is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

If they are sharp, the length is too short. Luckily they need to be adjusted longer, away from the neck, so there will be room for improvement by screwing the saddles so that the strings are a little longer.